# Search results on MSO don't need to specify "Public" - do they?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, meta

As far as I'm aware, there's no Meta infrastructure for Stack Overflow for Teams. Teams sites are "main" only, there is no meta equivalent.

As such, can we clear out the search results on MSO so that it doesn't say "Public"?

[image: Search results header reads "Public questions tagged [stackoverflow-for-teams]" instead of just "Questions..."]]

For Teams users - particularly those less familiar than myself with how Teams and Meta works - I can sort of understand it might be useful to make this absolutely clear but I think there may be another way to do this. As the image shows, the Teams content isn't in the left sidebar, so is there a need to be specific in the search results?

Perhaps, instead, when *posting* a question, Teams users see a banner warning them that all questions posted on MSO are public to prevent *asking* those questions here?

Comment: That's a bug on the search page rather than anything intentionally designed to safeguard posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed on SO for all non-team members and on other sites for everyone.